# Jade multiline raw text

Tags: pug, ejs, swig-template

I am building embeddable JS widgets with NodeJs and Express. Basically, call a route via script src and get back js in the browser. I have been using Jade, but the ability to output multi-line raw javascript without pipes on each line in the template is making me want to switch. I can't find any sane way to output multi-line raw text without using pipes on each line.

EJS can do this and assuming Swig can as well. Should I just switch template engines? EJS works but worry that ejs-local is not being maintained. Using Express 4.x with Node.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* have multi-line raw text in your templates, just add a dot (`.`) after the tag.

Example from [the docs](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag):

```
script.
  if (usingPug)
    console.log('you are awesome')
  else
    console.log('use pug')
```